# Java application not picking up app.properties on Widows 10

Tags: linux, windows, java, ssl, jdk

there is an application that needs certification to work fine, in Linux, there is no problem but I want to run this on a windows machine.
I have Installed Java on my windows 10 system.

then I Download that jnlp application to run it on my windows machine.
to running app correctly I need to create a properties file like "~/.app.properties". and in that file, I should point the app to my pem file and the ssh keys.
the File contains:

```
orca.xmlrpc.url=https://webpage.com/orca/xmlrpc
user.certfile=/Users/pruth/.ssl/file.pem
user.certkeyfile=/Users/pruth/.ssl/file.pem
enable.modify=true
ssh.key=~/.ssh/id_dsa
SSH Public key to install into VM instances
ssh.pubkey=~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
Secondary login (works with ssh.other.pubkey)
ssh.other.login=pruth
Secondary public SSH keys 
ssh.other.pubkey=~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
Should the secondary account have sudo privileges
ssh.other.sudo=yes
Path to XTerm executable on your system
xterm.path=/opt/X11/bin/xterm
```

After running this app it doesn't follow lines in the properties file but in Linux it does.

> Update: application tells that put properties file in $HOME/.app.properties, where i can find this folder in windows?

Comment: $Home indicates the same directory as the application typically

Comment: @Ramhound I put properties file the same directory as the application. still doesn't work.